# How to get only value part of linked list values from mule DB connector

Tags: linked-list, mule

I have the below flow which returns a list of values from DB with in mule.
I want to be able to get only the value part of the result from DB instead of a full linked list in the format of "column=value". I want to use the value part as part of a URL in the next http block. Please see my flow below. Any feedback will be helpful please.

```
<http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_Configuration" protocol="HTTPS" host="jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/#[flowVars.custID]" port="443" doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration"/>
<http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration1" host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>

<flow name="dbcconnectorFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration2" path="/lockStatus" allowedMethods="PUT" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <db:select config-ref="Oracle_Configuration" doc:name="Database">
        <db:dynamic-query><![CDATA[select CUST_NO FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE LOCKED='N']]></db:dynamic-query>
    </db:select>
    <logger message="#[message.payload]&quot;" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <set-variable variableName="custID" value="#[message.payload[0]]" doc:name="Variable"/>
    <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="/" method="PUT" doc:name="HTTP"/>
</flow>
```

Ekow

Answer (score 0):

One way to get only the value part of the result from DB is to put a transform message (Dataweave) component after the DB component and configure it as shown in this example:

```
    <flow name="myprojectFlow">
      <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/" doc:name="HTTP"/>
      <db:select config-ref="MySQL_Configuration" doc:name="Database">
        <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[select CompanyName from Customers limit 10]]></db:parameterized-query>
      </db:select>
      <response>
          <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
            <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
      %output application/json
      ---
      payload.CompanyName[1]]]></dw:set-payload>
        </dw:transform-message>
      </response>
    </flow>
```

The output is the first company name string in the array. The column name is not included.

Answer (score 0):

Found a way around this. I had to convert the db results which was an object into xml using the object to xml transformer. Then use the splitter to split the results since I was expecting multiple output as below

## [xpath3('//root/data/"xml_tag_of_required_data"', payload, 'NODESET')]. I then set the output as a variable and referenced the variable in the http endpoint URL.